# Issue Solidity, Blockchain, and Smart Contract Course - Patrick Collins

Tags: python, solidity, brownie

I am having an issue with the Fund me part of this course (16 hour video on YT) for brownie.
I am following Patrick and have the same set-up yet when I try to run this script I get an error he doesn't have:

> brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network rinkeby

Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

FundmeProject is the active project.

```
Running 'scripts/deploy.py::main'...
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 50, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 12, in main
    deploy_fund_me()
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 7, in deploy_fund_me
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from:account"}, publish_source=True)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 523, in _call_
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Final argument must be a dict of transaction parameters that includes a `from` field specifying the address to deploy from
```

---

Edit: needed more background info

The contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

// Smart contract that lets anyone deposit ETH into the contract
// Only the owner of the contract can withdraw the ETH
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

// Get the latest ETH/USD price from chainlink price feed
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";

contract FundMe {
    // safe math library check uint256 for integer overflows
    using SafeMathChainlink for uint256;

    //mapping to store which address depositeded how much ETH
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    // array of addresses who deposited
    address[] public funders;
    //address of the owner (who deployed the contract)
    address public owner;

    // the first person to deploy the contract is
    // the owner
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function fund() public payable {
        // 18 digit number to be compared with donated amount
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10**18;
        //is the donated amount less than 50USD?
        require(
            getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD,
            "You need to spend more ETH!"
        );
        //if not, add to mapping and funders array
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
    }

    //function to get the version of the chainlink pricefeed
    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256) {
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
            0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e
        );
        return priceFeed.version();
    }

    function getPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
            0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e
        );
        (, int256 answer, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        // ETH/USD rate in 18 digit
        return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
    }

    // 1000000000
    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1000000000000000000;
        // the actual ETH/USD conversation rate, after adjusting the extra 0s.
        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }

    //modifier: https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-tutorial-all-about-modifiers-a86cf81c14cb
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        //is the message sender owner of the contract?
        require(msg.sender == owner);

        _;
    }

    // onlyOwner modifer will first check the condition inside it
    // and
    // if true, withdraw function will be executed
    function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
        // If you are using version eight (v0.8) of chainlink aggregator interface,
        // you will need to change the code below to
        // payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);

        //iterate through all the mappings and make them 0
        //since all the deposited amount has been withdrawn
        for (
            uint256 funderIndex = 0;
            funderIndex < funders.length;
            funderIndex++
        ) {
            address funder = funders[funderIndex];
            addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
        }
        //funders array will be initialized to 0
        funders = new address[](0);
    }
}
```

Brownie-config.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  # - <orghanization/repo>@<version>
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - "@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1"
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

deploy.py

```
from brownie import FundMe
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account


def deploy_fund_me():
    account = get_account()
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from:account"}, publish_source=True)
    print(f"Contract deployed to {fund_me.address}")


def main():
    deploy_fund_me(
```

helpful_scripts.py

```
from brownie import network, config, accounts


def get_account():
    if network.show_active() == "development":
        return accounts[0]
    else:
        return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
```

.env

```
export PRIVATE_KEY=0x******f5a557bbb30bb35f8c9929ded41eb9a15******b066d72b44890******
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=97417cf50bab449c88c09debfe******
export ETHERSCAN_TOKEN=ZMFY1FUWR67X4RZYHHGR6S4NNX1G******
```

Comment: I also have added __init__.py in scripts as explained by Patrick, but haven't added it since this is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that this solve your issue, but you must correct your code:{"from:account"} ---> {"from": account}

Comment: Nice suggestion. Please use `Comments` to provide such suggestion not `Answer`. Please delete it ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the upgrades project and adding this part to `brownie-config.yaml` resolve for me:

```
networks:
  rinkeby:
    verify: True
```